# Is it possible to transform a string to a variable code name in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

This might be a very bizarre question (and probably I might be advised against doing such a weird thing) but if I have a string as in `v_str ='var_name'` and I want to transform the contents of that code into the actual code, is that possible in MATLAB? As in:

```
v_str = 'var_name'
x = make_string_to_code(v_str)
```

translates to the functioning code:

```
x = var_name
```

which simply transforms the string to actual code.

The only way I thought of doing this is by writing a file with that code and then on the next line executing that fine, but I wanted to avoid writing files every time that I want to do this.

Also, why is this so not recommended? Why is it so **bad**?

Comment: Yes, but [you don't want to](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/).

Comment: @excaza thank you. :D somehow I missed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use eval, but that doesn't mean you should, as others mentioned.

```
v_str = '2 + 2'
eval(['x = ' v_str]) % x = 4;
x = eval(v_str); % x = 4;
```

The documentation of `eval` can be found here: [eval](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eval.html)

Comment: so making variables out of strings is NOT recommended? Why so? (sorry if this is an obvious question)

Comment: @CharlieParker because it's bad programming practice in general to have no idea where your variables are coming from; it makes it very difficult to debug. You're also blindly executing *any* string, which is not at all secure. It's also highly inefficient, MATLAB's JIT compiler cannot optimize `eval` statements.

Comment: @CharlieParker See excaza's first comment on your original post.